# Glide JS jump returns "move.substr is not a function"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Attempting to jump with Glide 2.0.4 returns error "move.substr is not a function""

```
var slider1 = $('#Slider1').glide();
slider1_api=slider1.data('glide_api');
slider1_api.jump(3, console.log('move to 3'));
```

This was added code to triggers_multiple_targets.html example. (https://github.com/jedrzejchalubek/Glide.js/blob/master/examples/triggers_multiple_targets.html)

The buttons to jump to the slides work though; how is the API supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the library code I figured out that it needs to be formatted like this:

```
slider1_api('=3'); // jump to slide 3
```

The equal sign can also give a direction as ><

Answer (score -1):

Not `glide_api'` , try to use `api_glide`.

This should work:

```
slider1_api=slider1.data('api_glide');
```